# Converting irregular dates in R and the Tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a series of dates as follows

```
25 September 2019
27 April 2020
1994
28 February 2021
1986
```

Now I want to convert the 1994 and 1996 to:

```
01 January 1994
01 January 1986
```

Other full dates should be left as they are.

Any help is appreciated especially using the tidyverse way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given some vector `d` of dates and years:

```
> d
[1] "25 September 2019" "27 April 2020"     "1994"             
[4] "28 February 2021"  "1986"
```

Replace any entries with only 4 letters with those four letters with "01 January" pasted in front:

```
> d[nchar(d)==4] = paste0("01 January ",d[nchar(d)==4])
```

Giving:

```
> d
[1] "25 September 2019" "27 April 2020"     "01 January 1994"  
[4] "28 February 2021"  "01 January 1986"
```

Answer (score 2):

A regex solution, which identifies the "only-year" values using the anchors `^` (for string start position) and `$` (for string end position) as well as backreference `\\1` to recollect the "only-year" values:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(dates = sub("^(\\d{4})$", "01 January \\1", dates))
              dates
1 25 September 2019
2     27 April 2020
3   01 January 1994
4  28 February 2021
5   01 January 1986
```

`base R`:

```
df$dates <- sub("^(\\d{4})$", "01 January \\1", df$dates)
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  dates = c("25 September 2019",
            "27 April 2020",
            "1994",
            "28 February 2021",
            "1986")
)
```